# I have some code that might be interesting to share. Is this a good place to do so?

Tags: discussion

I have written some c++ (c++11) code, that in my opinion greatly simplifies writing LibraryLink code: automatic and templatized export/import of `MTensor` of any rank an type to (possibly nested) STL containers, `iostream`-like argument extraction (see [the github page](https://github.com/pisto/LibraryLink-Cpp11-example/blob/master/mathematica.cpp), function `coalesce` for a demo). With some polishing and documentation, I think it's something that might be handy to many.

Is stackexchange a good place to let this slip? Would that be regarded as spam?

Comment: There is a blog ... http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/archive/ ... you may want to write an entry

Comment: Interesting... but I guess I'd have to submit my writing to someone?

Comment: Just enter chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/ and leave a message for a mod

Comment: Yes, that would be a good blog post. And our blog neeeds some love right now:)

Comment: You can also post a fitting question and self-answer.  There are several excellent examples of that around,  e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/131

Comment: ok... probably a FAQ like question is best. I will tidy up the documentation and post. Or if you think that a blog entry is best, just let me know.

Comment: FAQ sounds a bit fuzzy...  Specific Q&As are usually well received. Good tidyings ;-)

Comment: Any updates maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't forget this but holidays plus other projects have pushed that back a little.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the best place to share it.  It would be better to also post it [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/428/what-third-party-packages-do-you-use), and you might consider Wolfram Community additionally.  You could also write a Q/A on the main site, something like "How can I simplify writing LibraryLink code?" or similar, then self-answer.  I don't regularly check meta and I didn't even know about this until someone showed me today.  I was also working on something (quite different) with the very same goal: make it easier to write LibraryLink code.

Comment: I wish Mathematica had something like CPAN / CRAN / CTAN for Perl/R/TeX, but dynamic and community maintained. The Wolfram Library Archive is slow, too bureaucratic, and there just isn't a lot of good stuff there.

Comment: For future packages, consider posting to http://packagedata.net/.  I already added this one.

Comment: Would you be open to migrating this to the main site and casting it as a self-answered question?  Something along the lines of "How can I write LibraryLink code more easily?" or "How can I cut down on the boilerplate necessary for LibraryLink?".  I could post my ow alternative solution as another possible answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am not maintaining this anymore, so I don't think it's a good idea to post this library around.